# Sphinx Sorting not working

Tags: sorting, ubuntu, search-engine, sphinx

in my table definition I have multiple `int` fields i.e. `id`, `verified` (this is int not bool) and `filesize`. I am able to sort by `id` but unable to sort by `verified` or `filesize`.

```
// Include Sphinx API file
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMaxQueryTime(300);
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id ASC');
$result = $s->query("test");
```

The above code works fine but instead if I use `$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@verified ASC');` or `$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@filesize ASC');` it's not working.

I tried something like

`$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id ASC, @verified ASC, @filesize ASC');`

And my Config file (partial) is like

```
sql_query     = \
 SELECT id, title, verified, filesize \
  FROM domains

 sql_attr_uint     =  id
 sql_attr_uint     =  verified
 sql_attr_uint     =  filesize

sql_query_info        = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id
```

After I edited my config file I used the following command to reindex the data

`sudo indexer item --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf --rotate --print-queries`

And, then restarted Sphinx by using `sudo service sphinxsearch restart` but still no luck.

I am need to sort the results by verified and filesize. How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
sql_attr_uint     =  id
```

id should not be declared as an attribute. Its not, its the document id :)
I think sphinx is just ignoring this line automatically; but its presence, just leads to confusion (because it does nothing)

But otherwise should try

```
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'verified ASC');
```

or

```
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id ASC, verified ASC, filesize ASC');
```

---

`@` is a prefix for special 'internal' values. `id` is considered special (its the document id), so should have the prefix. But normal attributes SHOULDN'T have it.